# Embedded google drive ordering

Tags: google-drive-api

Can we sort google drive files  to show the newest or last modified ones on the top ?? I only can see the list and grid option for showing files in iframe. If not , any advice or alternative solution for this issue that my client is facing it  ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the documentation you needed to [list files from the drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list).

> This method accepts the q parameter, which is a search query combining
>   one or more search terms. For more information, see the [Search for
>   Files and Team Drives](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) guide.

And you can actually sort it by using the parameter `orderBy`.

> A comma-separated list of sort keys. Valid keys are 'createdTime',
>   'folder', 'modifiedByMeTime', **'modifiedTime'**, 'name', 'name_natural',
>   'quotaBytesUsed', 'recency', 'sharedWithMeTime', 'starred', and
>   'viewedByMeTime'. **Each key sorts ascending by default, but may be
>   reversed with the 'desc' modifier. Example usage:
>   ?orderBy=folder,modifiedTime desc,name.** Please note that there is a
>   current limitation for users with approximately one million files in
>   which the requested sort order is ignored.

You can also test by [Try it now](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list#try-it).