# Sorting files in Google Drive Embedded Folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I am embedding a Google Drive folder's content into my website, via the following code (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20681974/how-to-embed-a-google-drive-folder-in-a-website)):

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

I am trying to sort it by name in **descending** order, but I have not been able to do so.

I tried with what was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553645/embedded-google-drive-ordering), but nothing seems to work.

Here are some of my attempts:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID&orderBy=name,desc#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=FOLDER-ID&orderBy=desc,name#list" style="width:100%; height:600px; border:0;"></iframe>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

**In the [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47553645/embedded-google-drive-ordering)**

`orderBy=folder,modifiedTime desc,name`

you are refering to:

`desc` refers to `modifiedTime`.

You should interpret the sample as:

"Order by ascending folder, descending modified time and ascending name"

**In your case:**

The r query for [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) should be `orderBy=name desc`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, it does not seem to work. Try [this](https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=1kyecM8NE5z8FAdkGJBwkQz794CTjCvho#list) vs [this](https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=1kyecM8NE5z8FAdkGJBwkQz794CTjCvho&orderBy=name%20desc#list).. Same result, but the second one has the "orderBy" clause.